# How do you unit test a function that clears properties?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I have a very common function that I have always unit tested in the same way, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution or if it's even possible a code smell is involved. It seems like a very simple case but I have a function that clears the properties of the object. Working in JavaScript, here is a simple example:

```
function Dog(name, owner) {
  this.name = name;
  this.owner = owner;

  this.reset = function() {
    this.name = '';
    this.owner = '';
  };
}

var puppy = new Dog('Max', 'Timmy');
console.log(puppy.name)  // logs "Max"
puppy.reset();
console.log(puppy.name)  // logs ""
```

I would normally unit test by setting the properties, calling the clear function, and then asserting that the properties were indeed set back to the defaults or "cleared out". The reason I'm asking about such a simple solution is because of the dogma that unit tests should only have 1 assertion. I also think that a "reset" type function could get way out of hand when it is dealing with a large number of properties (i.e. an object that is meant to store a SPA's state).

I'm sure that I am over-thinking this but wanted to get some outside opinion/criticism for something I have been doing the same for many years. I just cannot possibly think of a better way to do this.

Another question could be, are unit tests surrounding a reset function necessary? To me they seem to almost just test the language implementation -- similar to a getter/setter property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I test the functionality of a function that uses other functions in it?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/225323/how-should-i-test-the-functionality-of-a-function-that-uses-other-functions-in-i)

Comment: `...because of the dogma that unit tests should only have 1 assertion` - that's a bit over the top in my opinion. I'd say that unit test should - preferably - only have assertions that verify one type, or one aspect of behavior (and not just everything one could think of). It ensures that one bug doesn't hide other bugs. But it doesn't mean that there must be literally one assertion per test and no more.

Comment: While I agree with you @KonradMorawski, there still doesn't seem to be an efficient way if you are testing a function that clears a large number of properties. Maybe it's just me but I don't like having to constantly keep updating my `reset()` function every time I add a new property to the object. I will continue doing this, but was hoping for some enlightening/revolutionary solution :)

Comment: Dittos, @KonradMorawski. "one test, not one assertion" I say. I often `Assert` test data initial state. How else can you possibly prove `reset()` works if the initial state is not known/proven?  FURTHER, in the sense that I'm setting "state", then there may be several objecs/object-properties to test for the proper state.

Comment: @gnat: where do you see a function that uses other functions in the code above?

Comment: @DocBrown right there, in the question: "setting the properties [_that's other function_], calling the clear function, and then asserting that the properties were indeed set back to the defaults"

Comment: @gnat: I think you mixed something up. "Dog" is a Javascript-idiomatic constructor, it does not call "reset". Below that is the "unit test", it constructs the object (the "SUT") and calls the "reset" function.

Comment: The "one assertion" doesn't mean a single assertion statement, but that they assert "the single task was accomplished entirely", which may require multiple assert statements to validate.

Comment: @DocBrown I see, thanks. "Working in JavaScript", I missed that

Comment: Mutable state and side-effects *are* simply hard to test. There's no way around it. (Maybe that's a reason to avoid them?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit tests should cover logic, and as a matter of fact, `reset` doesn't contain any logic - there is no `ifs`, no `switch`es, no loops in it - basically, no conditional statements of any type.

And yes, it means that testing it sort of boils down to testing JavaScript as such, as you say. Set a, b, and c to empty strings! Have a, b and c been set to empty strings? Good. Good JavaScript!

So, given there's no *logic*, why would we want unit test coverage here at all?

I guess we'd wish to have it in order to protect ourselves against the scenario in which you're adding another property to the class, but then forget to reset it in your `reset` function.

The problem here is that you would also have to update your unit test to reveal this bug, and if you forgot about updating your `reset` function, it stands to reason you would have failed to update `testReset`, too.

Or your little special function that returns all the contents of your singleton, nicely packed for testing purposes.

One possible alternative would be to use reflection (in case of JavaScript, it's just iterating over properties of course) for resetting all properties in existence, and then only unit test it as a universal utility, even on an arbitrary stub class.

Of course you're likely to get into more problems if you want to actually preserve the value of some of your properties rather than wipe everything clean.

All in all, it's a difficult task because that's a singleton you have to reset. Singletons are notoriously bad for testability.

Misko Hevery devoted a series of articles and presentations to that. See:

- [Root cause of singletons (article)](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/25/root-cause-of-singletons/)
- [Singletons are pathological liers (article)](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/)
- [The Clean Code Talks - "Global State and Singletons" (video)](http://youtu.be/-FRm3VPhseI)

Comment: Singleton? Did I miss something in the code above?

Comment: -1 Because it has logic - just because it does not have any ifs does not mean it doesn't do anything. And at the very least a simple unit test will protect you from accidentally modifying any established functionality.

Comment: @DocBrown ctrl + F and "singleton" would quickly reveal where I got this crazy singleton idea from :) Not in the code above, but the OP mentions this contraint in comments under Cramps's answer: `"My example may have been a little too simplistic, but the object is a singleton (Angular service) that is injected into multiple controllers"`

Comment: @MaurycyZarzycki - `"at the very least a simple unit test will protect you from accidentally modifying any established functionality"` - did I not acknowledge that in my answer? `"I guess we'd wish to have it [the test] in order to protect ourselves against the scenario in which you're adding another property to the class, but then forget to reset it in your reset function."` I don't mind a downvote, there's no pleasing everyone, but it seems that at best you've only skim read my answer.

Comment: @KonradMorawski: that's funny, I ran a search by Ctrl-F before posting my comment - but I stopped the search when the first occurence was in your answer, did not look farther.

Comment: @MaurycyZarzycki I wrote that tests should cover logic. That's the basic litmus test of whether something should be unit tested (and that's not my original idea, but one coming from reputed experts such as Roy Osherove). I never wrote the reverse: that just because some code doesn't contain conditional statements, testing it is of no use. In fact, right now I'm writing unit tests verifying corectness of some raw SQL :) (for an Android project that can't use an ORM, because of some non-standard requirements about the db it uses)

Comment: @DocBrown sure thing. Btw I didn't write it in a mean or patronizing way, just to clarify ;) I could have mentioned the source of this notion in my answer, but there were only two at the time and it seemed much more visible than now...

Comment: @KonradMorawski: you wrote "given there's no logic, why would we want unit test coverage here at all" - for me, that actually sounds like "because the code doesn't contain conditional statements, testing it is of no use". Just my two cents. What I like about your answer is the scenario about what happens when one forgets to update the method in stake.

Comment: @DocBrown but what follows immediately after this rhetorical question is: `I guess we'd wish to have it in order to (...)`. And thanks. Well, that's the problem about this type of tests: since they have to mirror the implementation in order to work in the first place, they're not that much of a safety net

Comment: Maybe I just misread that part. I guess the main design problem with that object is the availability of such "reset" method - this looks like an error-prone construct, and one should question if it is needed at all. But we cannot answer this without knowing the context.

Comment: I'm really enjoying the discussion here, and I'd also enjoy hearing the alternatives to this `error-prone construct`. I don't necessarily enjoy it myself but I could not think of a better alternative. I wish I could give a better example but I feel this same conversation would arise with a method that resets properties to certain defaults. For example: how would I store state for an advanced search with fields such as timeframe, author, etc.? The tests would have to mirror the implementation and then, what is the point? There isn't a safety net at all unless I _somehow_ forget of of the two.

Answer (score 5):

You are over-thinking the "one assertion" rule/guideline.

The reason for the rule is that a test case should test only one "behaviour" of a class. By testing only one behaviour per test case, you make it much easier on yourself to pinpoint where an error got introduced when a test case starts failing.

The problem is that it is hard to tell when that basic rule of testing only one behaviour is being violated, also because people might disagree what falls under "one behaviour".
However, in the large majority of cases, the one behaviour that you want to test can be verified with a single assert statement. For that reason, the rule is being stated as "you shall have only a single assert".
For the minority of cases where a single, indivisible action of the class has multiple outputs and/or side effects (like your `reset` method), it is perfectly fine to have multiple assert statements. In fact, you are still asserting just one thing, namely that all properties have been cleared.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is two tests, one for each component of your reset function. Or more, if you have more. These would be pretty simple to create.

A key point of tests is to know what is failing when something fails. If you test the "reset" method and it fails you want to know *what* failed. While not super important in your example, other situations like this might be much less clear which part is failing.

By testing each individual variable, as long as your workflow is writing a failing test when you add new variables, say `Breed` to your dog, you will be forced to add `Breed` to the reset function because you immediately have a failing test.

Answer (score 0):

Probably instead of deciding based on some authorities view of best practices, it's better to remember *why* you are writing unit tests - such as you want to save time later by catching bugs early in development, prevent bugs from reaching users, and document the code for developers (and possibly for others).

The deciding principle, then, is whether the time spent writing the tests is justified in achieving those goals.  Of course, this is still a guess based on limited information, but that's the best that can be done.

How long will it take you to figure out the actual bug if you write one test versus N tests?  Which way will be more stable in the face of changing requirements?  In this case I personally would estimate that writing a large number of tests probably won't be worth the time, plus the semantics of "clearing out the properties" apparently implies that it should clear out future properties as well.  Note that this could technically be written in a single assertion anyway, for example:

```
assert.isTrue(myLibrary.propertyCollection(objectUnderTest).All(function(x) {x==='';}));
```

Whether this makes sense in your situation is something you can answer better than I can.

Answer (score -1):

You could add a function that returns the properties in their default state enclosed in an object and then another that returns their current state. Compare the returning values of each of those functions and assert accordingly.

In this particular example, you should be able to assert true that `puppy.reset().getNameAndOwner()` should be equal to `puppy.getDefaultState()`. (There's a link for Object comparison at the bottom of my post. Do NOT use `==` or `===`)

See below

```
function Dog(name, owner) {
   this.name = name || '';
   this.owner = owner || '';

   this.reset = function() {
       this.name = '';
       this.owner = '';
   };

   this.getNameAndOwner = function() {
       var name = this.name
           owner = this.owner;
       return { name: name, owner: owner };
   }

   this.defaultState = function() {
       var emptyName = '',
           emptyOwner = '';
       return { name: emptyName, owner: emptyOwner };
   }
}
```

How to compare objects:

[Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1068834/439793)
[How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201183/439793)

Comment: My example may have been a little too simplistic, but the object is a singleton (Angular service) that is injected into multiple controllers. Therefore, there is no constructor function.

Comment: @AdamBInfinity Well, in that case you could add a function that returns the state of each of the properties you're interested in, all of them enclosed in an object. In this case it would result in something like `{ name: 'Max', owner: 'Timmy' }`. Then you can compare `puppy.getNameAndOwner()` and compare it to `new Dog().getNameAndOwner()`

Or, if you don't have access to the constructor, add another function that returns the default state of those properties enclosed in an object, in this case `{ name: '', owner: '' }`, and compare _that_ to `puppy.reset().getNameAndOwner()`

Comment: This would work but it seems like more effort with no added benefits to accomplish the same thing as what I'm already doing. And in my case, I have ~8 state properties being maintained. I wouldn't want a function `getProp1AndProp2AndProp3`. Plus you are introducing functionality strictly for testing.

Comment: That would make the reset-test require a specific implementation of the constructor function, which is a dependency you would want to avoid. Changing the constructor suddenly breaks a completely irrelevant test.

Comment: @ArveSystad You're right. I changed it now since it wasn't a very practical approach.

Comment: @AdamBInfinity You don't have to name it that. You could use a more generic name, such as `getCurrentState`.

Functionality strictly for testing is one of the many problems that arise due to _methodology for the sake of methodology_ (in this case the assert once dogma). This solution remains true if you're willing to assert only once per test. However, you can opt to assert multiple times in one test and avoid all this hassle!

Comment: @Cramps I would upvote that comment if I could. And for that reason I think I'm going to be sticking with the way I've always done it. I honestly just wanted a discussion if somebody had a better way but it seems that the idea of one assertion means assert one piece of functionality. Which, in this case, means that reset resets all properties. Thank you.